# Strong user library like comparable to example java/go for node.js(javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

A quick look on stackoverflow I have not yet found(so hopefully this not duplicate question) similar one(also has long content). I also believe TJ holowaychuck who has created a lot of good node.js (javascript) libraries [concluded](https://medium.com/@tjholowaychuk/farewell-node-js-4ba9e7f3e52b#.o6up6719f) the same:

> The Go stdlib is something I thought was awful when I first heard of
>   Go, being so used to ultra-modularity in Node, and having experienced
>   most of Ruby’s stdlib rot. After getting into the language I realized
>   that most of the stdlib is pretty essential to programs these days,
>   compression, json, IO, buffered IO, string manipulation and so on. The
>   bulk of these APIs are well-defined, and powerful. It’s pretty easy to
>   get by writing entire programs with nearly only consuming the stdlib.

I am looking for a strong user library comparable to for example (java/go) but for node.js(javascript) . Preferable available via package manager(npm) and also very important should be well maintained. If not I think there should be one and programmers should work on it together. We could probably stitch a lot of good libraries together(from npm) and right real solid documentation for this?

For example I just summed up some packages from mostly java:

- [java.io](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) to provide file io

  > Provides for system input and output through data streams,
  >   serialization and the file system.

We have [fs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html) in node.js but I think might be to minimalistic. I have not yet found strong library for this? Sometimes we `pipe()` them together with stream libraries like for example [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2)

- [javax.swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) to have a GUI which looks (almost) some on all platforms

  > Provides a set of "lightweight" (all-Java language) components that,
  >   to the maximum degree possible, work the same on all platforms.

For this we maybe have [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or [nwjs](http://nwjs.io/)? I also like [riot.js](http://riotjs.com/) for it's simplicity but not yet full of features. We also have [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) from twitter just to name a few?

- [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

  > Utility classes commonly useful in concurrent programming.
  >   I know we don't really have threads(concurrency in node.js) but still I think some of these classes could also be in strong user library? Or for example channels like in Go. We have generators/[co](https://github.com/tj/co). There also a lot of good promise libraries like for example [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). There are also some channel library on top of generators like for example [js-csp](https://github.com/ubolonton/js-csp).
- [java.math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/package-summary.html)

  > Provides classes for performing arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic (BigInteger) and arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic (BigDecimal).

But also a lot of other math functions. Again I believe there are already some good ones available but it is hard to find them?

- [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

  > Provides the classes and interfaces of the JavaTM 2 platform's core logging facilities.

Good logging libraries like for example [bunya](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan).

- [java.util.zip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

  > Provides classes for reading and writing the standard ZIP and GZIP file formats.
- [java.util.collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)

  > Contains the collections framework, legacy collection classes, event model, date and time facilities, internationalization, and miscellaneous utility classes (a string tokenizer, a random-number generator, and a bit array).

Like for example the collections from java are really good. I guess you have [collectionsjs](http://www.collectionsjs.com/) for that? For time [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)?

---

This is more for javascript development but I really like solutions like for example [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to not create monolithic beasts. What do you people think. Which libraries do you guys use really a lot for specific use cases(strong user library?). Maybe we should have a poll per category??

P.S: this list is not even complete yet if you ask me but already very long.

Answer (score 0):

Efforts are underway to build such a standard library. One such effort is [stdlib](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib), of which I am a contributor. While the project has an emphasis on [numerical computing](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/develop/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/ndarray/array) functionality (including [statistics](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/develop/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/stats), machine learning, and other [math](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/develop/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/math/base/special)), the library also provides more generic [utilities](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/develop/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/utils) commonly found in various libraries and on npm. The project is available for use via npm, has a strong user focus, and prioritizes high-quality (and unified) documentation. Hope this helps!